# Error JavaScript - for y if

Tags: javascript

Alguien conoce cómo podría realizar un `alert` diciendo: "intentos se terminaron". En el `else` no se podría porque se repetiría cada vez que se ejecute el `script` , ¿Cómo podría hacer algo así?

Este es mi codigo.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    var Tuedad = prompt("escribe tu edad");

    if (Tuedad==18) {
        alert("yeahh");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = tunombre; 
    } else {
        alert("Error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con comprobar al terminar el `for` que no se ha acertado la edad con un `flag` bastará:

```js
var bool=false;
for (var i = 0; i < 3 && !bool; i++) {


 var Tuedad = prompt("escribe tu edad");


 if (Tuedad==18) {

 alert("yeahh");
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = tunombre; 
 bool=true;
 }else{

  
    alert("Error");

 }
}
if(!bool){
 alert("intentos se terminaron");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Si no entiendo mal lo que intentas hacer el problema no es dónde poner el mensaje de intentos consumidos. Ese mensaje debería mostrarse una vez finalizado el for si ningún resultado ha sido correcto, es decir debería estar después del for.

Lo que tienes que hacer es que una vez que un intento sea correcto no continue preguntando.

Mira este ejemplo:

```js
var tunombre = 'Pepe';

function comprobarEdad() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var Tuedad = prompt("escribe tu edad");
    if (Tuedad === '18') {
      alert("yeahh");
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = tunombre; 
      return;
    }else{
      alert("Error");
    }
  }
  alert('No hay más intentos');
}

comprobarEdad();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```